# Inserting into Excel using OleDb overwriting the wrong row multiple times

Tags: excel, oledb, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into an existing Excel spreadsheet using an `OleDbConnection`. I am noticing that when I insert, even though I specify a sheet offset, it is still writing to the wrong row. Even worse, every record is getting written to the same row! Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string destination = @"C:\publish\output.xlsx";
    File.Copy(@"C:\publish\template.xlsx", destination, true);
    string connectionString = getConnectionString(destination);
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"
INSERT INTO [Advertisers$A3:AC] 
VALUES
(
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
)";
            // Spit out 29 bogus values
            for (int i = 0; i != 29; ++i)
            {
                addParameter(command, "Value = " + i);
            }

            // Insert 1200 records
            for (int i = 0; i != 1200; ++i)
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static string getConnectionString(string path)
{
    OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
    builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0 Xml");
    builder.DataSource = path;
    return builder.ConnectionString;
}

private static void addParameter(OleDbCommand command, object value)
{
    OleDbParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "?";
    parameter.Value = value == null ? DBNull.Value : value;
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

Comment: Im glad you had this problem, I wasnt able to insert several rows with an offset, so your code really helped me! Thanks Travis!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically copied this same code to a different console application and it worked as expected. Hmm? After comparing the two projects for a while, I noticed that under the project properties, under `Build`, the `Prefer 32-bit` check box was checked. Unchecking it fixed my issue!

[image]